Passing Custom Field Values from Sale Order Line to Stock Moves in Multi-Step Delivery Processes in Odoo
I have created two custom fields, one in sale.order.line and another in stock.move. When a sale.order is confirmed, it creates a stock.picking with product details in stock.move. I want to pass my custom field value from sale.order.line to stock.move.
I can achieve this in a one-step delivery setup by using _prepare_procurement_values. However, in two-step and three-step delivery setups, the custom field value does not carry over to the subsequent moves, and it ends up as None in the second and third moves.
How can I ensure that my custom field value is correctly passed to all moves in multi-step (two-step and three-step) delivery setups?
def _get_stock_move_values(self, product_id, product_qty, product_uom, location_dest_id, name, origin, company_id,
                           values):
    res = super()._get_stock_move_values(product_id, product_qty, product_uom, location_dest_id, name, origin,
                                         company_id, values)

    type_id = values.get('type_id')
    res.update({
        'type_id': type_id,
    })
    print('res..................',res)
    return res


I'm not fully sure, but you also have to overwrite stock.move._prepare_procurement_values() to add your values there.
Right after the first move is created by the procurement it will automatically be confirmed. On confirmation Odoo will create another procurement, if there is set up a multi-step route. And the values for that new and also other later procurements (for stock moves!) are set up in that mentioned method.
def _prepare_procurement_values(self):
    """Overwritten to add type_id to procurement values"""
    result_dict = super()._prepare_procurement_values()
    result_dict["type_id"] = self.type_id.id
    return result_dict


Thank you very much, Czoellner, for your helpful response. I was able to find the same solution as well!
